# "brand spanking new" - is this correct grammar & polite way to say?

Tags: word-choice

I saw an add saying "This iphone is brand spanking new" which sound like "brand *** new".

I am not sure if this word has correct grammar + polite (ie people use it without any bad or joke meaning)

Comment: It is correct, polite and in common use.  It is just emphasis.

Comment: Why do you suspect its grammaticality? Where do you find the possible error? Can you elaborate?

Comment: **spanking** [as submodifier]: *a spanking new conference centre* http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spanking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no connection to *spank = slap, smack [with the open hand]*. OED says of ***spanking***...

> *Etymology:  Of doubtful origin. Compare Danish (and North Frisian) **spanke** to strut.*

Their first citation for sense 1: *Very big, large, or fine; exceptionally good in some respect, freq. with implication of showiness or smartness.* is 1666.

The more specific sense 5: *Used as adv. Very, exceedingly; esp. as **spanking new**, brand-new* is first recorded in 1886.

---

Note that all these adjectival/adverbial usages are designated ***Chiefly dial. and colloq.*** by OED.

---

EDIT: [This NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brand%20spanking%20new%2Cspanking%20new&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbrand%20spanking%20new%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspanking%20new%3B%2Cc0) confirmed my suspicion that a significant proportion of all instances  of the very common *spanking new* occur as ***brand*** spanking new. But [by far the more common phrasing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brand%20spanking%20new%2Cspanking%20new%2Cbrand%20new&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbrand%20spanking%20new%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspanking%20new%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbrand%20new%3B%2Cc0) is [*brand new*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brand_new) - extant 1570, original metaphoric allusion unknown to most speakers today. It seems a bit odd that we can just slot *spanking* into the middle of a well-established set phrase like that.

Possibly, in the minds of some speakers *spanking* has connotations of *smacking, **striking[ly]***, but it's really just a *syntactic* element [(function word?)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/function+word) whose sole purpose is to intensify an adjacent *semantic* element that actually *has* "meaning" (in this case, either the adjective ***new***, or the set phrase ***brand new***, depending how you see it).

Although OED offers *very, exceedingly* as "definitions/synonyms", idiomatically you *can't* just substitute either of those in *brand **????** new*. The only syntactically/semantically compatible word I can come up with is [*brand **fucking** new*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brand%20fucking%20new%2Cfucking%20new&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfucking%20new%3B%2Cc0) (which though vulgar is perfectly valid *grammatically*).

To me, the usage *brand **spanking** new* seems to reflect that of *fucking* and [*abso-**bloody**-lutely*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=abso-bloody-lutely&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=abso-bloody-lutely&aqs=chrome..69i57.12705431j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8) i.e. - an intensifier is "infixed" into a single word or set phrase.

I was therefore gratified to find my guess for a credible usage was [*abso-spanking-lutely*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22abso-spanking-lutely%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=%22abso-spanking-lutely%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.12154868j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8) spot on! There's a couple of dozen people who've also noticed that relatively uncommon syntactic flexibility allowing "infixed intensifier" usage - without the potential drawbacks of vulgar *fucking, bloody*.

Comment: thax you very much for your answer

Comment: 'Spanking' also gets used as an intensifier of size, usually as a 'a spanking, great mcguffin'. Unfortunately google hits for that use have been rather swamped by witty reviews of '50 Shades of Grey'.

Comment: While there is no _etymological_ connection to ‘slap/smack’, there almost certainly is a mental one for most people—at least enough for folk etymologies like the one mentioned in ZeroBugBounce’s answer to appear. (Also, I’ve never heard the word _spanke_ in Danish, though it is in the dictionary; its derivative _spankulere_ is reasonably common. My etymological dictionary of Danish takes it back to PG _*spannakōną-_, derived from _*spannaną-_ ‘tighten, fasten, strain, stretch’, itself from PIE _*spon(d)-ne-_, thus relating it to [span/spin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=span).)

Comment: @Janus: Certainly ***I've*** never thought of ***spank = smack*** as a semantic element in the usage *brand spanking new*. To me, it's just a word that *in certain contexts* can be used as an intensifier (as per my "infixed" ***fucking*** example). But maybe I've simply seen it so often I no longer register any exotic allusions. I just checked, and there are far more written instances of *a **spanking** good [X]* than *a **belting** good X*, and I can't deny the latter has stronger overtones of violence / punishment to me (presumably because it's less familiar, and not yet totally cliched).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's correct and it is a polite phrase (not profane and not considered rude).  It is a rather colorful phrase, though, and it basically means the same thing as "brand new".  It is an English idiom (a saying) and it means something that is very new.

The "spanking" supposedly refers to the old practice of doctors spanking newborn babies in order to help clear their lungs and start their breathing immediately after birth.

Comment: I don't disagree with the general answer of ZBB, but I would note that if I were writing, I'd probably avoid in formal usage, except, perhaps, in a passage of dialog.

Comment: @brasshat It tends to be used mostly in marketing, which tends towards hyperbole like this. Kind of like _new and improved_.